# storing an image locally from a path string in json in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a json string like this

```
"images/medium/110a3d7866490506377dacd2712a229757a.jpg"
```

how can i store this in localstorage.setitem
and then display it?
thanks.

Comment: store it as an image file so i can display it from the cache, offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the image to a data-uri and then store it as a string in local storage. 
So you will want to load the image into canvas and then export it as a dataURI.

check out [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage) for a solution